# Merge unix/win/mac new lines with update to win new line

Tags: windows, oracle, macos, unix

I have a column in my oracle database which gets filled via OS independent application user interface (unix/win/osx).
Due to copy paste in the different operating systems, i have multiple different new lines (chr(10), chr(13)||chr(10), chr(13)) in my column.

What i need to do now, is: 
Update all different new lines to one, which is windows: chr(13)||chr(10).
Although the amount of new lines in the columns must stay the same!
Biggest Problem is, that the new lines can also be in the same cell. So we can also have
chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10) equals unix + win
which should result in:
chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10) equals win + win

I have tried multiple different statements, i cant seem to get it right.

My best try:

> select
>   dump(replace(replace('Test1'||chr(10)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3',chr(10),chr(13)||chr(10)),chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13),chr(13)||chr(10)),17),
>   from dual;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might have better luck using regexp_replace

based on your data in the comment below..  see the following

```
with testdata as(
SELECT  'Test1'||chr(10)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3' A, 'Test1'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3' b FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test1'||chr(13)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3' A,  'Test1'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3' b FROM dual
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Test1'||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3' A, 'Test1'||chr(13)||chr(10)||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3' FROM dual
)
,re as (
SELECT A  src, b tgt
, REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE(A, '('||chr(13)||chr(10)||'+)', chr(7),1,0,'m'), '['||chr(10)||chr(13)||']', chr(7)), chr(7), chr(13)||chr(10) ) newsrc
FROM testdata)
SELECT DUMP(src, 17) src, DUMP(tgt, 17)  tgt, DUMP(newsrc,17) newsrc
,(case when newsrc = tgt then 'MATCH' else 'NONMATCH' end) matching
from re;
```

where i have replace windows newlines with chr(7) then replaced remaining \r's and \n's also with chr(7)..
and finally converted all chr(7) back to \r\n

it certianly works for your test data...

```
SRC                                                          TGT                                                          NEWSRC                                                       MATCHING
------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ ------------------------------------------------------------ --------
Typ=1 Len=18: T,e,s,t,1,^J,T,e,s,t,2,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3         Typ=1 Len=19: T,e,s,t,1,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,2,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3      Typ=1 Len=19: T,e,s,t,1,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,2,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3      MATCH   
Typ=1 Len=18: T,e,s,t,1,^M,T,e,s,t,2,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3         Typ=1 Len=19: T,e,s,t,1,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,2,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3      Typ=1 Len=19: T,e,s,t,1,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,2,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3      MATCH   
Typ=1 Len=13: T,e,s,t,1,^J,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3                   Typ=1 Len=14: T,e,s,t,1,^M,^J,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3                Typ=1 Len=14: T,e,s,t,1,^M,^J,^M,^J,T,e,s,t,3                MATCH
```

Comment: `'Test1'||chr(10)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3'` => `'Test1'||chr(13)chr(10)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3'`

`'Test1'||chr(13)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3'` =>
`'Test1'||chr(13)chr(10)||'Test2'||chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3'`

`'Test1'||chr(10)chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3'` => `'Test1'||chr(13)chr(10)chr(13)||chr(10)||'Test3'`

Comment: works great for my database, thank you a lot ShoeLace